# JOptionPane ignores OptionPaneUI specified in UIDefaults

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, look-and-feel

I want to override BasicOptionPaneUI with my own OptionPaneUI. However, JOptionPanes I create still get painted by BasicOptionPaneUI.

Here is the initClassDefaults-Method in my custom look and feel:

```
@Override
protected void initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) {

  super.initClassDefaults(table);
  final String packageName = "my.own.plaf.ui.";

  System.out.println(table.get("OptionPaneUI"));

  Object[] uiDefaults = {
    "ButtonUI", packageName + "MyButtonUI",
    "OptionPaneUI", packageName + "MyOptionPaneUI",
  };
  table.putDefaults(uiDefaults);

  System.out.println(table.get("OptionPaneUI"));
}
```

And my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MyOwnLookAndFeel());
  } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
  System.out.println("My UIClassID is: " + optionPane.getUIClassID());
  System.out.println("Current implementation: " + optionPane.getUI().getClass().getSimpleName());
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ping");

}
```

The output I get is

```
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI
my.own.plaf.ui.MyOptionPaneUI
My UIClassID is: OptionPaneUI
Current implementation: BasicOptionPaneUI
```

and an option pane that is igoring my UI. MyButtonUI, which I define the same way works like a charm.

What do I overlook?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the thing I overlooked was to override the createUI()-Method so that it returns a new MyOptionPaneUI.-.-